# C# take group with the same field form list

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to take, from a list, a group of elements which have the same field  (direction field - look to code), and then take first item which occurs in list (myList order), checking if it is ok with if and take it.

Next, I want to take next direction (if exist), create a group and again take first element.

I don't know how many groups it will be at any step. I just know it will be max 4 group. How can I do this?

```
List <myClass> myList = allCreatedObjects;

class myClass
{
  Control c; 
  Direction d;
}

public enum Direction
{
  up, down, right, left,
}
```

Comment: Any efforts? Did you tried something `foreach` with `if .. else` at least?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `linq`, for example to select `right`:

```
var rightGroup = myList.Where(c => c.d == Direction.right);
```

If you want to do this automatically for all the enum values, you can use a loop like:

```
foreach (Direction direction in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Direction)))
{
    var groupList = myList.Where(c => c.d == direction);
}
```

This will result in a couple of variables.

You can also use linq like this:

```
var group = from item in myList
            group item by item.d into g
            select new { key = g.Key, listItems = g.ToList() };
```

This will result in an object, with the direction as key, and listItems filled with the items. If you want empty lists for the non-added directions you'll need to join with the direction enum.

As for a more exotic example:

```
var group = from item in myList
            where item.d == Direction.left //some condition on item
            group item by item.d into g
            where g.Any(c => c.d == Direction.up) //some condition on the group
            select new { key = g.Key, values = g.ToList() };
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want exactly. but if you want to group by direction, then in each direction check some condition, you may try as following:

```
var output = new Dictionary<Direction, List<myClass>>();

foreach (myClass cls in myList)
{
    //check some condition based on cls properties 
    if (cls.c is TextBox && cls.d != Direction.down)
    {
        output[cls.d].Add(cls); //add it to output
    }
}

//each item in output[direction] is of type List<myClass>
var upList = output[Direction.up]; //this is as List<myClass>
//var downList = output[Direction.down]; //this is as List<myClass>
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<myClass> myList = new List<myClass>
{
    new myClass(){c = new Button(), d = Direction.down },
    new myClass(){c = new Button(), d = Direction.left },
    new myClass(){c = new Button(), d = Direction.right },
    new myClass(){c = new Button(), d = Direction.up },
    new myClass(){c = new TextBox(), d = Direction.down },
    new myClass(){c = new TextBox(), d = Direction.left },
    new myClass(){c = new TextBox(), d = Direction.right },
    new myClass(){c = new TextBox(), d = Direction.up },
};

public class myClass
{
    public Control c;
    public Direction d;
}

public enum Direction
{
    up, down, right, left,
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var groups = myList.GroupBy(my => my.d);
    var firstElems = groups.Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
}
```